# What is the point of edit sessions?

Tags: ace-editor

When do they occur and when would I use one? I'm adding listeners to the editor and editor.session and setting, editing and retrieving the text numerous times. Will I ever need to worry about a session changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are useful if you want to create tabbed editor, which can edit multiple files. To do that you create one editor, and a session for each file.
Then you can use `editor.setSession` to show selected file in the editor.